# Using Revision with Views

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I'm creating a page to list any content that needs moderation, which in my case includes new content and pending revisions.

I have the pending revisions down, by setting

- Fields

  - Content: Nid
  - Content revision: Title (Title)
  - Content revision: Updated date (Last Revised)
  - Content revision: Vid
- Filter Criteria

  - Content revision: State (= Pending)
  - Content: Revision moderation (=Moderated)
  - Content: Published (YES)

Now how do I add in content that hasn't been published that requires moderation, BUT don't pull prior content that has been set to unpublished?

I've tried opening up the filter for Content:published and selecting the ANY option and excluding it from display. However, When you unpublish content, the revision for it asks for moderator attention as if it was a new revision waiting to be published. So it grabs ALL unpublished content as opposed to only the new content waiting to be published.

Comment: Can you clarify: can we assume you're using "Revisioning"?

Answer (score 1):

For your revisions, I assume you're using the [revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) module.

Why not just remove the Content: Published filter entirely?  Any node with a pending revision should be moderated.

On my site, when I unpublish a node, unpublishing it alone does not cause it to have a pending revision.  In other words, if the most recent version of a node is published, unpublishing that node does not create a pending revision.

However, if you unpublish a node with a pending revision, that node will still have a pending revision after it is unpublished.  There is no way to use views alone to distinguish between a node with a pending revision that was "set" to unpublished and one that isn't published yet.

To implement such a workflow, I would suggest using the [flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) and [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) modules.  Roughly, the steps I would take would be:

1. Create a global flag called "Intentionally unpublished."
2. Create a rule that automatically flags nodes when they are unpublished.
3. Add the flag as a relationship to your view and filter based on the existence of the flag.